# Is it possible to style CSS based on user's zoom?

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar, nav

I recently started coding my site using HTML and CSS and today, I got information from my friend that my site wasn't looking good in another browser, then I cross-checked my site with other browsers and unfortunately, I am having problems with cross-browser confirmations.

The problem is, whenever people do zoom like 110%, my button navigation bar starts to break into pieces. Only Chrome is supporting my site's view and only at 100% zoom or otherwise it will also make my nav bar break into pieces. See the screenshots below to see the difference:

Correct view: https://postimg.org/image/aymnhz541/

Broken Bar View: https://postimg.org/image/99zm3l7s7/

I am using position absolute and relative properties to those navbar buttons but I also tried float properties which do not seem to solve my problem. I even checked by changing from Pixels (px) to percentages (%) for margins and terms but nothing changed.

So my exact question is, is there any CSS property or line or code which could act like this:

A) whenever user do zoom, I could code the difference like if they zoom-out then my buttons get small with codes like reducing width on that action without breaking my navbar?

(If user do zoom by 110%, then navbar should be of 110% size and if user do zoom out to 75% then my navbar should be of 75% of original size.)

Or, if there is any other solution to prevent my navbar from getting broken in parts, please let me know. I want my navbar to stay same.

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
.contact {
    background-color: #767676;
    color: white;
    margin: -4px;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: -5%;  
    float: right;
    padding: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px; }

.contact:link {
    color: white; }

.contact:visited {
    color: white; }

.contact:unvisited {
    color: white; }

.contact:hover {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: #336699;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none; }

.homin {
    position: static;
    background-color: #767676;
    border: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    color: white;
    width: 10%;
    padding: 1.6%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px;
    cursor: pointer; }

.homin:link {
    color: white; }

.homin:visited {
    color: white; }

.homin:unvisited {
    color: white; }

.homin:hover {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: #336699;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none; }

/* Dropdown2 Button */

.Wds {
    background-color: #767676;
    color: white;
    margin: -4px;  
    width: 110%;
    padding: 18%;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0px;
     }

.Windows {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; }

.Windowsdropdown2-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin: 4px;
    margin-left: -4px; }

.Windowsdropdown2-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block; }

.Windowsdropdown2-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.Windows:hover .Windowsdropdown2-content {
    display: block;
    z-index:9999; }

.Windows:hover .Wds {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: #336699;
    font-weight: bold; }

/* Dropdown3 Button */

.Mc {
    background-color: #767676;
    color: white;
    margin: -4px;
    width: 110%;
    padding: 18%;  
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0px;
     }

.Mac {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; }

.Macdropdown2-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin: 4px;
    margin-left: -4px; }

.Macdropdown2-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block; }

.Macdropdown2-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.Mac:hover .Macdropdown2-content {
    display: block;
    z-index:9999; }

.Mac:hover .Mc {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: #336699;
    font-weight: bold; }



/* Dropdown3 Button */

.Lx {
    background-color: #767676;
    color: white;
    margin: -4px;  
    width: 110%;
    padding: 16%;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0px;
     }

.Linux {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; }

.Linuxdropdown2-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin: 4px;
    margin-left: -4px; }

.Linuxdropdown2-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block; }

.Linuxdropdown2-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.Linux:hover .Linuxdropdown2-content {
    display: block;
    z-index:9999; }

.Linux:hover .Lx {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: #336699;
    font-weight: bold; }


/* Dropdown5 Button */

.Us {
    background-color: #767676;
    color: white;
    margin: -4px;  
    position: relative;
    width: 140%;
    padding: 11%;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0px;
     }

.USB {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; }

.USBdropdown2-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin: 4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-right: 0px; }

.USBdropdown2-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block; }

.USBdropdown2-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.USB:hover .USBdropdown2-content {
    display: block;
    z-index:9999; }

.USB:hover .Us {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: #336699;
    font-weight: bold; }

/* Dropdown5 Button */

.Serv {
    background-color: #767676;
    color: white;
    width: 120%;
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding: 8%;
    padding-bottom: 4%;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0px;
     }

.Server {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; }

.Serverdropdown2-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin: 4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-right: 0px; }

.Serverdropdown2-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block; }

.Serverdropdown2-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.Server:hover .Serverdropdown2-content {
    display: block;
    z-index:9999; }

.Server:hover .Serv {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: #336699;
    font-weight: bold; }
```

HTML Code:

```
<a href="link" class="homin">home</a>

<div class="Linux">   <button class="Lx">HowTo Guides</button>   <div class="Linuxdropdown2-content">
    <a href="link">link name</a>
    <a href="link">name</a>
    <a href="link">See More >></a>   </div> </div> <div class="Windows">   <button class="Wds">HowTo Fixes</button>   <div class="Windowsdropdown2-content">
    <a href="link">link name</a>
    <a href="link">name</a>
    <a href="link">See More >></a>   </div> </div> <div class="USB">   <button class="Us">Virus And Hijackers&nbsp</button>   <div class="USBdropdown2-content">
    <a href="link">link name</a>
    <a href="link">name</a>
    <a href="link">See More >></a>   </div> </div> <div class="Server">   <button class="Serv">&nbsp5xx Server Error Solutions&nbsp</button>   <div class="Serverdropdown2-content">
    <a href="link">link name</a>
    <a href="link">name</a>
    <a href="link">See More >></a>   </div> </div> <a href="link" class="contact"> name</a>
```

Comment: Design it responsively.

Comment: Please prove sample code jsfiddle or codepen for easy debugging..Setting the navbar alone to % may not help during zoom out

Comment: Hi, thanks for replies. I am using w3schools tryit to view code first. but I am unable to do anything. I am updating my code on my question. See first question post please and let me know.

Comment: When asking questions, please (a) always present code using the code formatting button, not the quote button, (b) use a separate block for every file, (c) refrain from asking volunteers for urgency anywhere in your question, but especially not in the title.

Comment: @halfer Okay, thanks. Wasn't aware of code formatting button though.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no, you cant style based on browser zoom. However, there are things you can take into consideration. Like container width vs fluid, positioning, etc. It would be more helpful if you added a fiddle of your code and not just an image.

Comment: Hi Rob, I just updated my question with actual code. Please take a look and let me know. Please please, check any possible problem in it, very kind of you.

Comment: can you post your html code too? also there is no html or css line in the css code on the top

Comment: do you have this in the head section?  '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">'

Comment: I posted both codes, html and css related to navbar

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the window.devicePixelRatio (JS), if you want to know the zoom state of the user.
So for example a zoom of 125% will be a pixel ratio or 1.25

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1920px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25) {
  //your styles here
}
```